# Need help calling & running complex object property using MVC

Tags: javascript, object, dom, model-view-controller

I've been told to transfer my code to MVC and I've encountered a problem doing so.

I need it done in the way shown below:

```
var model = {
    demo: document.getElementById('demo'),
    colour: document.getElementsByTagName('li').item(0),
    size: document.getElementsByTagName('li').item(1),
    visible: document.getElementsByTagName('li').item(2),
    position: document.getElementsByTagName('li').item(3),
    swap: document.getElementsByTagName('li').item(4),
    report: document.getElementsByTagName('li').item(5)
};

var demoOn = model.demo.onmouseover;
var demoOff = model.demo.onmouseout;

var view = {
    col: {newCol: model.demo.style.backgroundColor = 'rebeccapurple', oldCol: model.demo.style.backgroundColor = 'darkcyan'},
    siz: {newSiz: model.demo.style.width = '600px', oldSiz: model.demo.style.width = '400px'},
    vis: {newVis: model.demo.style.opacity = '0', oldVis: model.demo.style.opacity = '1'},
    pos: {newPos: model.demo.style.margin = '0 0 0 200px', oldPos: model.demo.style.margin = '0'}
};

var controller = {
    changeCol: function() {
        demoOn = function () {
            return view.col.newCol;
        }
    }
};
controller.changeCol();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/meys5x6n/

I expect it to change the background colour of my div demo once the element colour property has been hovered over but nothing is happening at all.

Comment: please add the relevant code here instead of posting jsfiddle links :)

Comment: tried for 20m but I kept getting format errors

Comment: i recommend to use that built-in code editor. It works quite fine

Comment: fixed it i think